# Are there any SUSY black holes in D > 5?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, supersymmetry, supergravity

Quoting from [arXiv:0801.3471](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3471)

> Asymptotically flat BPS black hole solutions are known only for $d = 4,\,5$.

and I've seen this claim very timidly suggested in a couple of other places, but I couldn't find a proof.

We could define a supersymmetric black hole as such:

- Solution to some supergravity theory
- Asymptotically Minkowski, but not Minkowski
- Has a Killing vector which is asymptotically time-like (stationary)
- Has a Killing spinor
- Regular down to horizon, including no diverging scalars (so type IIA D$0$ does not count)

Do they exist for $D>5$? Is there a proof of non-existence? Or have any counterexample been found in the last ten years?

**Progress**: I have managed to prove there are no SUSY black holes in $D=6$. The vector bilinear from a symplectic Majorana

$V^\mu \epsilon^{AB} = \bar\eta^A \gamma^\mu \eta^B$

is null because of a Fierz identity. Thus we have an always null Killing vector and combined with the other timelike Killing with a spatially compact Killing horizon it's enough to derive a contradiction. This is compatible with the classified 6D SUSY geometries I've found in, e.g., [arXiv:hep-th/0306235](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306235).

**Progress 2**: it appears to me like [arXiv:hep-th/0504080](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0504080) provides a supersymmetric black hole in 7D. Though I still need to check whether the scalars don't diverge.

Comment: In my naivete I thought D-branes were all black-hole-like in sugra. Is this wrong?

Comment: p-branes with $p>0$ are only asymptotically flat in the orthogonal directions, and the D$0$ has a divergent dilaton so it's not really a regular solution of the classical sugra.